# How are the $\sigma_k(x)$ functions in the Weierstrass Polynomial derived from the Residue Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, several-complex-variables

On p. 70 in Griffith's "Introduction to Algebraic Curves", the author states in a proof of a Lemma regarding the construction of a polynomial as a Weierstrass Polynomial, the Newton Symmetric Polynomials, $\sigma_k(x)$ are holomorphic as a consequence of the residue theorem and equal to the result given in the image below. I'm not sure how this derivation of the result given in the text comes from the residue theorem. Can anyone walk me through this in some detail?
Please note: The text does not state the Residue Theorem

page 69:

[image: Page 69 of Griffith's Introduction to Algebraic Curves]

page 70:

[image: Page 70 of Griffith's Introduction to Algebraic Curves]

Comment: Welcome to MSE - it is generally considered best practices to avoid pictures from textbooks and to instead write out mathematical formulas in the body of the question. Here's a tutorial to get you started on how to format math equations on this site: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . Next, you reference the residue theorem as provided in the text, but do not include the statement in your post - this makes your question difficult to answer without the book, which answerers may not have. Please include the statement in your post.

Comment: The text itself does not state the Residue Theorem, it only references it as in the images. Should I try to add an annotation somewhere which states the Residue Theorem?

Comment: The information that the text does not state the residue theorem is valuable too - please include it. You should also add the version of the residue theorem you're familiar with as well as your attempts to make it work for you in solving this problem and where it comes up short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Residue Theorem (in fact the Argument Principle) just gives
$$
\sigma_k(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|y|=\epsilon}y^k \frac{f_y(x,y)}{f(x,y)}dy
$$
Now we use that $f$ is holomorphic to apply Leibniz rule to show that $\sigma_k$ is holomorphic and its derivative is
$$
\frac{d\sigma_k(x)}{dx} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|y|=\epsilon}y^k \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{f_y(x,y)}{f(x,y)}dy = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|y|=\epsilon}y^k \frac{f_{xy}(x,y)f(x,y) - f_x(x,y)f_y(x,y)}{f(x,y)^2}dy
$$

Comment: Thank you for responding @Alan Muniz, but I'm still not seeing how $$
\sigma_k(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|y|=\epsilon}y^k \frac{f_y(x,y)}{f(x,y)}dy
$$ is derived in the first place? More specifically ....the $$y^k$$ term.

Comment: It is the argument principle. If $D$ is a disc with boundary $C$ and $f$ is holomorphic on $D$ then $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C y^n\frac{ f'(y)}{f(y)}dy = \sum_z z^n$  where $z \in D$ runs over the zeros of $f$ counted with multiplicities.

Comment: See the first application here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle and any standard complex analysis book such as Conway's

Comment: thank you, this helps immensely, I think the next hurdle in completely is understanding this in the context of the set up in Griffiths' Text. Namely,  if we have $$g(x,y)= y^k$$  and we apply this to the functions $\sigma_k(x)$ given in Griffiths, the set up on p.69 call $$y_v(x)$$ the zeroes of $$f(x,y)=0$$,  how do we get this k-th power of y?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand your question...

Comment: If we start with $f(x,y) = y^n$ then all $\sigma_j$ and $a_j$ are identically zero as $y_\nu(x) = 0$ always.

Comment: Pardon, let me rephrase, I guess now I can see how this fits into the generalized argument principle form that is in the Wikipedia article for some $$g(x,y)$$ , but where did he decide to make $$g(x,y) = y^k$$ to be honest, that part is what confused me the most. I'm not quite seeing where this particular $$y^k$$ part would come from given the set up on page 69 and page 70.

I understand that each k corresponds to every $$k=1,..,d$$, just not sure how that piece fits in for that $$g(x,y)$$ if we look at this as an application of General Argument Principle.

Comment: This works the same way one uses the Residue Theorem to compute sums of infinite series. One just cook up a function that gives the right residues and compute some integral. Now we want $y_1(x)^k + \dots + y_n(x)^k$ so we use $y^k \frac{f_y(x,y)}{f(x,y)}$. The clever thing is to change from $a_j$s to $\sigma_j$' so that this argument works.

Comment: Okay that's leading me in the right direction, thank you once again!